# Deep clone an object in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: recommended solution for deep cloning/copying an instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156120/java-recommended-solution-for-deep-cloning-copying-an-instance)

I have an object which has to be cloned. However while cloning it should also clone the objects inside it. How is this possible ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Java Deep-Cloning library The cloning library is a small, open source
>   java library which deep-clones objects. The objects
>   don't have to implement the Cloneable interface. Effectivelly, this
>   library can clone ANY java objects.

```
Cloner cloner = new Cloner();
MyClass clone = cloner.deepClone(o);
```

So and here is example [cloning](http://code.google.com/p/cloning/).

Answer (score 7):

You must be aware that this is not a well-defined problem and deep-copying cannot be properly done in a mechanized, fully automatic way. These are some of the options:

- Java has the `clone` protocol, but it's considered deprecated for most scenarios nowadays;
- you can use serialization to serialize-deserialize in-memory;
- you can write so-called copy constructors.

Answer (score 2):

You need to override `clone()`  method as such

```
public class Person implements Cloneable{
 private Long id;
 private Address address

  @Override
  protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
  //do deep cloning
  }

 }
```

**Also See**

- [Proper way to deep copy with copy constructor instead of Object.clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199429/proper-way-to-deep-copy-with-copy-constructor-instead-of-object-clone)

Comment: Better point OP to a page discussing all the gotchas and pitfalls of properly implementing `clone` :) For example, never create the clone using `new`, but `super.clone`.

Comment: @ Jigar I think you are talking about shallow cloning not deep cloning

Comment: @PramodKumar The `clone` mechanism is neither deep nor shallow per se. It depends on how you implement it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to implement a deep copy is to serialize and then deserialize the object. Look up `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach to deep cloning is to use `Java serialization`, where you `serialize` and `deserialize` the object and return the deserialized version.

Comment: A disadvantage of this is ofcourse that the class and everything that it refers to must be `Serializable`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of cloning is to provide a **copy constructor** to construct a new instance based on the data of the provided instance:

```
public MyClass(MyClass instanceToCopy)
{
   ...
}
```